# AttributeError: module 'torch.fft' has no attribute 'fftfreq'

Tags: python, pytorch, fft

I followed the example from
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.fft.fftshift.html#torch.fft.fftshift

```
import torch.fft
f = torch.fft.fftfreq(4)
a = torch.fft.fftshift(f)
print(a)
```

and got the error

> AttributeError: module 'torch.fft' has no attribute 'fftfreq'

I tried pip torch==1.7.0+cu110 and pip torch==1.7.1+cu110 and also conda pytorch==1.7.1 with cudatoolkit=11.0.
Others have the same problem https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/unable-to-use-correctly-the-new-torch-fft-module/104560/6
But changing to torch1.7.0 didn't solve the problem.

How to use torch.fft correctly?

Comment: Your code is working for me with `torch.__version__ == '1.8.1+cu111'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function [`torch.fft.fftfreq`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.8.0/fft.html?highlight=torch%20fft%20fftfreq#torch.fft.fftfreq) was introduced in [*PyTorch version 1.8.0*](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-1.8-released/). You need to upgrade to this version or higher in order to use it.